# How to remove Safari.app's "Favorites" Bookmark folder

Tags: macos, safari, monterey, bookmarks

This is Safari version 15.6 (17613.3.9.1.5) running under macOS 12.5 (Monterey).

I'd like to remove the Safari Bookmarks folder. It's easily emptied, but I've found no way to move it (putting it at the end of the Bookmark list would be an improvement) or delete it. Neither Google, nor the Apple user communities, nor this Stack return any useful advice on this issue. Apple certainly doesn't want the user to do this.

Is it possible to delete this Bookmark folder? If so, how?

Comment: You *do* realize that "favorites" is nothing more than the Favorites bar at the top of the Safari window designed to hold frequently accessed bookmarks? It is like the ~/Documents (and pictures, and music and movies....) folders. you don't **have** to use them but you can't delete them. So your best bet is to just ignore them.

Comment: Can you explain why you'd like to remove it? Maybe there's an alternative solution.

Comment: @JBallin No great reason: I need none of them (usual targets I access using Alfred from the keyboard) and would like the list of Bookmarks to begin (at least) with mine. This is not existential.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove this folder since it represents the bookmarks bar shown when the Bookmarks menu is accessed (as has been pointed out in the comments).

It's not just a pre-created folder; it's a built-in folder that cannot be modified.

Answer (score -2):

Rename the actual folder (wherever that resides???) putting a 'full stop' at the start of the word Bookmark so you'll have `.Bookmarks` or `.Favourites`. This may work but you've probably tried this already.

Another option is to look into the `defaults` command in the Terminal.app with caution obviously. I would `>` the output from the Terminal to a text file for the Safari defaults and the NSGlobal domain.

I'm no expert but that is where I'd start.

Comment: A reasonable thought, thanks. But it's a system-created folder, and its name cannot be modified.